# Pawn movement error

Tags: c++

I had recently started working on a chess engine in c++ for an university project but i have a problem in my pawn movement function. I know that the pawn is supposed to move one square forward or attack one square in diagonal. Well my function allows the pawn to attack blank spaces and i do not know why. My board is divided in 2 pieces: one that remembers which player a piece belongs to and one that has the name of the piece (like q,Q,p,P... and blank spaces). A hint would be more than welcome. (sorry for my poor English skills)

The code looks like this:

```
bool move_P(int move_start_i, int move_start_j, int move_finish_i, int move_finish_j, char table[][9])
{
    switch (table[move_finish_i][move_finish_j])
    {
        case ' ':
        {
            if (move_start_i - 1 == move_finish_i) // move pawn
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        default:
        {
            if (move_finish_i == move_start_i - 1 && move_finish_j == move_start_j - 1) // atack pawn ^<-
            {
                if (player[move_finish_i][move_finish_j] == player[move_start_i - 1][move_start_j - 1])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (move_finish_i == move_start_i - 1 && move_finish_j == move_start_j + 1) // atack pawn ->^
            {
                if (player[move_finish_i][move_finish_j] == player[move_start_i - 1][move_start_j + 1])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `move_start_i - 1 == move_finish_i` doesn't it depend on the color if `-1` or `+1`?

Comment: oh forgot to mention that i have a function that reverses (upside down) the table so the movements are always up

Comment: Also you may considder adding the [`en passant Capture`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_%28chess%29#Capturing) and the abillity to move two squares if he is on his starting rank.

Comment: Thanks @AntiHeadshot, but for the moment i am trying to make it simple and working. In the future i will consider adding more complex rules and maybe an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player check is wrong,

```
player[move_finish_i][move_finish_j] == player[move_start_i - 1][move_start_j - 1]
```

has to be

```
player[move_finish_i][move_finish_j] == player[move_start_i][move_start_j]
```

also you should use

```
return player[move_finish_i][move_finish_j] != player[move_start_i][move_start_j];
```

The main problem is the check for

```
move_start_i - 1 == move_finish_i
```

you have to add a check for the `j` position!

Comment: @aalin i updated the answer, theres more you missed, if he wants to move diagonal and its empty you use the first checkt

Answer (score 1):

Insert a

```
break;
```

statement at the end of the `case ' ':` block. Otherwise the default block is executed too if `table[move_finish_i][move_finish_j]==' '`, which explains why the pawn can move diagonally to blank squares.

Also, the curly brackets after the case and default are not needed. Think of case and default statements as jump labels, code is executed beginning at the first matching case until you leave the `switch() {...}` block with a break statement (regardless of further 'jump labels').